# Accessing JSON key with spaces in a foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am trying to access withing foreach some of the key values in the **example JSON below**.

```
{
  "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": 
    {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "EUR",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "Euro",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "USD",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "1.14122552",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-08-14 05:07:51",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    },
    {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "EUR",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Euro",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "0.87692400",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-08-14 05:09:17",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

The problem is that the keys are having spaces.

My **FOREACH** looks like this

```
$json = json_decode($data);    
$json_response = array();
foreach ($json->Realtime Currency Exchange Rate as $row) {
        $row_array = array();     
        $row_array['From'] = $row->1. From_Currency Code;        
        $row_array['To'] = $row->3. To_Currency Code;
        $row_array['value'] = $row->5. Exchange Rate;                           
       array_push($json_response, $row_array); 
 }
```

I have tried to use the key in the foreach statement as `['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'], [Realtime Currency Exchange Rate], [Realtime.Currency.Exchange.Rate]` and anything else I could find in here, but none of them worked.

**EDIT**
Also tried like this but it didn't work

```
foreach ($json->{'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'} as $row) {
    $row_array = array();

        $row_array['From'] = $row->{'1. From_Currency Code'};

   array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
}
```

But this **SOLUTION** worked

```
foreach ($json as $row) {
    $row_array = array();

        $row_array['From'] = $row->{'1. From_Currency Code'};

   array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
}
```

Any idea how I can access the key and its value?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you json_decode to an array instead with `, true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
$json->{'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'}
```

Hope that helps

Update:

```
$data = array(
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate" => array(
        0 => array(
            "1. From_Currency Code" => "EUR",
            "2. From_Currency Name" => "Euro",
            "3. To_Currency Code" => "USD",
            "4. To_Currency Name"=> "United States Dollar",
            "5. Exchange Rate" => "1.14122552",
            "6. Last Refreshed" => "2018-08-14 05:07:51",
            "7. Time Zone" => "UTC"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "1. From_Currency Code" => "USD",
            "2. From_Currency Name" => "United States Dollar",
            "3. To_Currency Code" => "EUR",
            "4. To_Currency Name" => "Euro",
            "5. Exchange Rate" => "0.87692400",
            "6. Last Refreshed" => "2018-08-14 05:09:17",
            "7. Time Zone" => "UTC"
        )
    )
);

$data = json_encode($data);

$json = json_decode($data);    
$json_response = array();
foreach ($json->{'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'} as $row) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Formatted JSON string will look like this

```
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": [{
        "1. From_Currency Code": "EUR",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "Euro",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "USD",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "1.14122552",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-08-14 05:07:51",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }, {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "EUR",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Euro",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "0.87692400",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2018-08-14 05:09:17",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I have tried like his foreach ($json->{'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'} as $row) { and then $row_array['From'] = $row->{'1. From_Currency Code'}; But the result is null

Comment: I updated my answer. Please accept my answer if that helped you

Comment: Yes, it does. thanks